# Can i use existing variables in powershell read-host

Tags: powershell

i am writing a simple script in powershell using "read-host  -prompt" so that i can input some text that will then be used to create some environment variables.

Is there a way that the subsequent times the script is run, the read-host message will show an existing value for the variable if it exists ? and if not what i want then accept my new input to change that variable ?

for example ...

$myvar = read-host -prompt "whats your value" and i enter 10 to set $myvar value to 10

next time the script is run, "whats your value" will show 10, and if i press enter without changing the value it will use the value 10 again .. if i enter a new value it will update $myvar to the new value

Thanks for any help

Comment: have you tried it yet? [*grin*] yes, you can use a $Var in your `Read-Host` call. take a look at the `-Prompt` parameter ...

Comment: Please clarify "subsequent times the script is run", does the scipt close/exit when finished? if so then the value of `$myvar` will not persist. You will either have to have the script modify itself (not advised) or have an external configuration file that it loads in to pull the previous value and to push the new value to before the script closes.

Comment: hi .. thanks for replying.. is there not a way to set the variable as a user variable so that it persists between powershell sessions ... can be seen from a cmd prompt etc ?

Comment: No. You can't do this in any language. Code, variables, functions, etc., only exist in the scope, session they are called in.  To do what you ask, you need to save this info somewhere on the fileSystem (txt, csv, xml, json, ini) or the registry, that you then can re-read as needed.

Comment: If you want something that is initially defined to some value whenever you begin a session,  put the definition into your $profile file.  If you want to store the value in a semipermanent way between seesions,  use an environment variable.  Use both techniques together if you want a variable initialized to a semipermanent value.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for two features that are *not* implemented in [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) as of PowerShell 7.1:

- (a) ***Pre-filling the edit buffer* with a *default value***, which the user can either accept as-is or modify.

  - The alternative is just to *inform* the user, via the `-Prompt` string, what value will be used if they don't enter a new one, but that way you won't be able to distinguish between the user choosing the *default* value or simply wanting to *abort* the prompt (which they could do with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, however).
- (b) ***Keeping a persistent history* of user-entered values** that remembers (at least) the most recently entered value, *across PowerShell sessions*.

Note: `Read-Host` is currently bare-bones. The module that provides the rich interactive command-line editing experience for PowerShell itself is `PSReadLine`, and would be great if its features, which include a persistent history and modifying the edit buffer, could be made available to user code for *general-purpose* prompting - see [GitHub proposal #881](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/881).
Surfacing such enhancements *via `Read-Host`* is probably the best option, or at least the ability to prefill the edit buffer could be implemented there: see [GitHub proposal #14013](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14013).

See - limited - custom implementations of (a) and (b) below.

---

(a) is currently only possibly via a *workaround*, and only *on Windows*, both in *regular console windows* and *Windows Terminal* (it does *not* work in the [obsolescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) PowerShell ISE <sup>Thanks, [CFou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14463444/cfou).</sup>, and in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal it only works if you place the focus on it by clicking immediately after launching a debug session):

```
# The (default) value to pre-fill the Read-Host buffer with.
$myVar = 'This is a default value.'

# Workaround: Send the edit-buffer contents as *keystrokes*
# !! This is not 100% reliable as characters may get dropped, so we send
# !! multiple no-op keys first (ESC), which usually works.
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys(
  '{ESC}' * 10 + ($myVar -replace '[+%^(){}]', '{$&}')
)

$myVar = Read-Host 'Enter a value'  # Should display prompt with value of $myVar
```

Note: The `-replace` operation is necessary to *escape* characters in the default value that would otherwise have special meaning to `.SendKeys()`.

(b) requires you to implement your own persistence mechanism, and the obvious choice is to use a *file*:

Here's a simplistic approach that only stores *the most recent* value entered.

- Supporting multiple historic values per prompt would also support for *recall* in `Read-Host`, such as as using up-arrow and down-arrow to cycle through the history, which is *not* supported as of PowerShell 7.1.

```
# Choose a location for the history file.
$historyFile = "$HOME/.rhhistory"

# Read the history file (which uses JSON), if it exists yet.
$history = Get-Content -Raw -ErrorAction Ignore $historyFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$defaultValue = 'This is a default value.'

# Get the 'myVar' entry, if it exists, otherwise create it and use the default value.
$myVar = 
  if (-not $history) { # no file yet; create the object to serialize to JSON later
    $history = [pscustomobject] @{ myVar = '' }
    $defaultValue
  } elseif (-not $history.myVar) { # file exists, but has no 'myVar' entry; add it.
    $history | Add-Member -Force myVar ''
    $defaultValue
  } else {  # return the most recently entered value.
    $history.myVar
  }

# Prompt the user.
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys(
  '{ESC}' * 10 + ($myVar -replace '[+%^(){}]', '{$&}')
)
$myVar = Read-Host 'Enter a value'

# Validate the value...

# Update the history file with the value just entered.
$history.myVar = $myVar
$history | ConvertTo-Json > $historyFile
```

Comment: This can also be done in 'straight' Powershell:

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Jim");  $a = read-host -prompt 'Name'

It requires: Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Comment: @jimbirch, yes, but this isn't any "straighter" than using `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys()`, which has the advantage of not requiring a separate `Add-Type` call.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this straight :

```
####[int]$myVar = 10           Read too fast the question :)
#$myVar = Get-ItemProperty ...
#or
#myVar = Get-Content ...
$tempVar = Read-Host "Enter the value ($myVar is default)"
if ($tempVar)
{
   $myVar = $tempVar
}
$myVar
# Store $myVar in the registry or in the file for next run
```

My bad, I answered without a good reading :) As @postanote said,
If you need to keep a track of the value from each run, you can store it in a file (IMHO, I would avoid the profile.ps1) or in a personal registry key.
Then read the file or the registry value to initialize your variable.