# Powershell populate user entry automatically

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to automatically populate a user input such as Read-Host automatically?

An example would be:

Script checks if a file name is over 20 characters. If it is then it asks the user to type a new file name under 20 characters, but auto populates the input line so they don't have to type the whole thing and can just modify the existing one.

Many thanks

---

Say if filename is "filename1"

Read-Host "Please enter new filename"
would give:
Please enter new filename: [user types a new filename here]

but i'm trying to make it do the following:
Please enter new filename: [filename1]

So the existing filename appears as if the user has typed it, so they can then modify it and press enter

Comment: You may have to resort to using a VB.NET class; see [SS64 on `Read-Host`](https://ss64.com/ps/read-host.html)

Comment: Cheers Jeff, I'm a beginner so that could be useful in future but I've editied my original post to have more detail:

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64753638/45375) to the linked duplicate for a (Windows-only) solution.

Comment: Perfect solution from yourself on the other question mklement0, thanks!